# Response/Reply pattern vs. method overloading in API design

Tags: java, design-patterns

I recently design an API to wrap data store implementation and allow other developers to use this API to index their data and query data base on keyword. I was using Response/Reply pattern in query method because Jaroslav Tulach mentioned that it can avoid keep changing API interface when adding parameter is needed(page 97 in Practical API Design). Other developer argues using method overloading is better approach. Can you share your experience of using 2 difference approaches in your design? Following is conversation between me and other developer.

Me:
Response/Reply pattern looks to be clean way to do since more and more parameters could be added into API interface with evolution of API. Having more than 10+ overloading methods in interface could just confuse other developers. How they figure out which method to use?

Other developer’s argument:
With evolution of API, you shouldn’t keep adding parameters. If you keep adding parameters in API interface, there is an issue with your API design. As a result, number of overloading method is small so it won’t bother developers. What’s more, large number of overloading method implementation is often seen in Java framework.

Me:
It’s easily to manage back-compatibility for previous version of API. You don’t have to change interface. Changing interface will breaks other developer’s existing code.

Other developer’s argument:
If I change implementation and add arguments, other developer should be updating their code based on new API. if new arguments are optional why bother adding it.

Comment: Not sure if everybody understands what is meant by "Response/Reply Pattern" . I don't. Can you provide some reference?

Comment: @Sameer: He did: `page 97 in Practical API Design`

Comment: response/reply pattern on wiki. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response

Answer (score 2):

> Other developer’s argument: With evolution of API, you shouldn’t keep adding parameters. If you keep adding parameters in API interface, there is an issue with your API design.

That's a rather naive view. All API's do evolve. It's not something which we want, but tell me one customer/client that get the specifications done right the first time...

The request/reply type of arguments is great since it's very easy to get backward comparability. We do not have to modify existing code either once the second version of the api has been created.

Consider this:

```
public class GetUserRequest
{
    string Id;
}

public class GetUserReply
{
  string Id;
  string DisplayName;
}
```

And the API interface:

```
public class MyCoolApi
{
    GetUserReply GetUser(GetUserRequest request);
}
```

(the structure of the API depends on the type of implementation)

Now we get a new requirement: All users should have the age included.

We'll just follow the open/closed principle and inherit the reply class:

```
public class GetUserReply2 : GetUserReply
{
  string Id;
  string DisplayName;
  int Age;
}
```

All version 1 users will deserialize version 1 while the version 2 users deserializes it as version2.

Same goes for incoming parameters. You could make the service (API) class a proxy (proxy pattern) which just invokes the correct api implementation in the background depending on the Request class version.

Conclusion: Request/Reply gives us a lot more flexibility contra method overloading.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we are comparing

```
   invoke( int param1, string param2) { ... }

   invoke ( string param3, int param4, int param5) { ... }
```

and so on for all valid parameter combinations

with

```
   invoke(requestClass theRequest)
```

which is used like this

```
   request.set("param1", value);
   request.set("param2", value);
   invoke(request);
```

There are several trades-off here.

A downside of the request approach is that the caller can provide an invalid combination of parameters and will receive no compile time warning - errors are not uncovered until runtime.

But the ever-growing interface may get completely out of hand, you can get a combinatorial explosion in the number of methods you need.

You can view SQL as an example of a very rich request - it seems clear to me that there are situations where a well structured query language or request object is preferable to a parameter-by-parameter method overloading approach.

My personal rule of thumb: if you're heading for 10 different overloaded methods a request object should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

There are no essential differences, neither can reduce the inherent complexity. Of course we can always find supporting use cases for either choice; without knowing your specific problem domain, others can't just pick a favorite based on some abstract principles.

I'll advise though to choose a solution that is simple for today. Don't worry about "future changes"